# Eclipse Editor Detach and place next to console, problems, and other tabs

Tags: eclipse

I would like to detach an editor tab from eclipse and place it along with the other tabs like Console, Problems, Search, Javadoc, etc.

Right now if I detach an editor tab, it still forms a part of the editor as such. It just splits my editor's 'screen real-estate'; into 2 or 3. I would like to split the editor tab into 2 or 3 and group it along with other views. This will allow me to minimise a views group which will also minimise some editor tabs along with it. This is not possible right now. Is there a plugin that will allow me to do so?

Not sure if I made myself clear. Let me know, and I can create a screenshot or a diagram to explain this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console, Problems... are views. You can't place an editor in a view tab-folder.
For more infomation, you can view the eclipse help documents. (Help-->help contents: Workbench User Guide > Getting started > Basic tutorial)

Comment: Oh.. I know that :) I was just wondering if you can create a group of editors perhaps.. Meaning split the editor component into 2 or 3 and expand and minimize the set of the editors..

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.. Editors can only be placed in the only one 'editor area'. Even if you split them into more than one 'group', you can not seperate them form each other like views do. So if you click minimize, the whole editor area will be minimized, not only the group...